# concatenating sub-elements of XML using sed

Tags: xml, parsing, sed

I have a large xml file that I need to load into a list with a pre-defined format. It has many sub-elements  like this:

```
<tag1>
  <tag2>element 1</tag2>       
  <tag2>element 2</tag2>
  <tag2>element 3</tag2>
  ...
</tag1>
```

I would like to combine these sub-elements into a single string to look like this:

```
<tag1>
  <tag2>element 1;element 2;element 3;...</tag2>
</tag1>
```

The actual paths to the tags are more complex.

Since the number of sub-elements is typically very large, I want to pre-process the file to simplify the list conversion process. I tried using XQuery but it was very slow (possibly because I did not know how to optimise it). I assume this is quite efficient using XLST also, but I don't have time to work out how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I solved the problem:

```
cat file | tr '\n' '±' | sed 's/<\/tag2>±<tag2>/;/g' | tr '±' '\n'
```

I have used tr to substitute all the LFs with a character I know does not appear in my file (±), then searched for the end tag followed by ± followed by the start tag and replaced it with a ";". Then I have used tr again to restore the LFs.

By piping the sed output to another sed substitution you can "flatten" as many tags as you want, which is exactly what I need since I have several tags I need to flatten. This has reduced the lines in my file by 95%, making the rest of the parsing very simple.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, possibly XSLT would work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:template name="extract-item" match="/">
  <xsl:element name="tag1">
    <xsl:element name="tag2">
      <xsl:for-each select="//tag1">        
            <xsl:apply-templates select="tag2"/>        
      </xsl:for-each>
     </xsl:element>  
  </xsl:element>  
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And python script using lxml library to do transformation:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import lxml.etree as ET

dom = ET.parse('C:\Path\To\XMLFile.xml')
xslt = ET.parse('C:\Path\To\XSLTFile.xsl')
transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)
newdom = transform(dom)

tree_out = ET.tostring(newdom, encoding='UTF-8', pretty_print=True)
print(tree_out)
```